# Python3 interpret unicode literal string as unicode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

Now I have some unicode literal string like "\\u0061" which is by default interpreted as 6 unicode character. How can I convert it into unicode character 'a' ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even easier:

```
>>> "\\u0061".encode().decode('unicode-escape')
'a'
>>>
```

Comment: @Amadan He sad he has `"\\u0061"`

Comment: Your answer is perfect.

Comment: I saw, which is why I deleted the comment. No, I didn't downvote, though it's probably because it's pretty much a duplicate of Anthony Sottile's.

Comment: I just click the upvote button but then a downvote appears. Is it my misoperation?

Comment: @jay Nothing it was there already, so , because you have less than 15 rep so unable to up-vote, BTW Thanks a lot for accepting, happy that i helped, 

Comment: This is worse because it forces a full conversion to bytes and back just to transform.  Using `codecs.decode` is a text->text conversion.

Comment: (also it's pretty bad form to essentially rip off an answer, edit in after the fact, and then beg for acceptance)

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the `unicode-escape` codec:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> print(r'\u2603')
\u2603
>>> print(codecs.decode(r'\u2603', 'unicode-escape'))
☃
```

Comment: @Jay. Then select the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.